# Mapping from presentation layer to backend the generic way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, layered

I have a web application `(webforms)` with layered tiers `(presentation-BLL(service)-DAL` and repositories with entity framework, and doing it all the generic way.

The system function very well, but the problem is that I am exposing domain objects right through to the presentation layer. I want to do a `switchover/mapping` in the service layer, but I cannot figure out how to do that the generic way.

In my presentation layer I have the following call:

```
var language = repository.GetByID<Language>(Guid.Parse("18022719-faa0-447a-b054-3e1ae6dd8c67"));
```

In my servicelayer the method looks like:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get instance from database by ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T GetByID<T>(Guid ID) where T : class
    {
        return iow.GetRepository<T>().GetByID(ID);
    }
```

It all wraps in a `unitofwork` (iow).

My headache is that presentation layer references a entitylike model which basically are flattened domain objects. Servicelayer are referencing this model as well AND, of course, the domainmodel for talking to database. In the case of the language entity in presentationlayer the fullname is `Model.Language` and in servicelayer it will be `DAL.Language` (to be passed on backwards).

I cannot figure out how to change type to the next call, generically:

```
return iow.GetRepository<T>().GetByID(ID);
```

Any suggestions...?

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you need to either introduce domain knowledge into your architecture, or you need to use convention and reflection.  Here are three ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

**Option 1:**

Since the presentation model is a higher order concept whose consumers are ultimately dependent on the lower entity layers, you can try a one way coupling of the presentation model to the entity model via an implicit operator that you will have to manually implement (or code generate).  Take the following as an example:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Language
    {
        public static implicit operator Model.Language(DAL.Language language)
        {
            return new Model.Language()
            {
                /* map values here */
            }
        }
        public static implicit operator DAL.Language(Model.Language language)
        {
            return new DAL.Language()
            {
                /* map values here */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can substitute one model for the other and let the implicit operators convert between them.

**Option 2:**

Specify a mapper class that is to be instantiated to handle the mapping.  Try the following which decouples the two models but still requires domain specific code to either be written or generated:

```
public  class   Presentation<TPresentationModel, TDALModel, TMapper>
        where   TMapper : Presentation<TPresentationModel, TDALModel, TMapper>.BaseMapper
{

    public  abstract    class   BaseMapper
    {

        public  abstract    TDALModel           ConvertPresentationModelToDALModel(TPresentationModel presentationModel);
        public  abstract    TPresentationModel  ConvertDALModelToPresentationModel(TDALModel dalModel);

    }

}
```

Option 3:

Use reflection and a convention of properties having the same name between the models.  Something like this:

```
public  class   Entity
                <
                    TEntity,
                    TDataObject,
                    TIBusiness,
                    TPrimaryKey
                >
        where   TEntity     : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TIBusiness, TPrimaryKey>
        where   TDataObject : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TIBusiness, TPrimaryKey>.BaseDataObject, new()
        where   TIBusiness  : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TIBusiness, TPrimaryKey>.IBaseBusiness
{

    public
    abstract    class       BaseDataObject
    {
        public  TPrimaryKey Id;
    }

    public      interface   IBaseBusiness
    {
        TDataObject GetByID(TPrimaryKey id);
    }

    public  class   PresentationMapper<TPresentationModel>
            where   TPresentationModel  : new()
    {

        private
        static  Dictionary
                <
                    string, 
                    MemberInfo
                >                   entityFieldsAndProperties       = typeof(TDataObject).GetProperties().AsEnumerable<MemberInfo>().Union(typeof(TDataObject).GetFields().AsEnumerable<MemberInfo>()).ToDictionary<MemberInfo, string>(memberInfo=>memberInfo.Name);

        private
        static  Dictionary
                <
                    string, 
                    MemberInfo
                >                   presentationFieldsAndProperties = typeof(TPresentationModel).GetProperties().AsEnumerable<MemberInfo>().Union(typeof(TPresentationModel).GetFields().AsEnumerable<MemberInfo>()).ToDictionary<MemberInfo, string>(memberInfo=>memberInfo.Name);

        private TIBusiness          business;

        public                      PresentationMapper(TIBusiness business) { this.business = business; }

        public  TPresentationModel  GetByID(TPrimaryKey id)
        {
            var dataObject  = this.business.GetByID(id);
            return this.map(dataObject);
        }

        private TPresentationModel  map(TDataObject dataObject)
        {
            var returnModel             = new TPresentationModel();
            var presentationMemberInfo  = (MemberInfo) null;

            foreach(string key in entityFieldsAndProperties.Keys)
            if (presentationFieldsAndProperties.TryGetValue(key, out presentationMemberInfo))
            {
                this.copy
                (
                    value:  this.getValue(from: dataObject, @using: entityFieldsAndProperties[key]), 
                    to:     returnModel, 
                    @using: presentationMemberInfo
                );
            }
            return returnModel;
        }

        private object              getValue(TDataObject from, MemberInfo @using)
        {
            return @using is PropertyInfo ? ((PropertyInfo) @using).GetValue(from) : ((FieldInfo) @using).GetValue(from);
        }

        private void                copy(object value, TPresentationModel to, MemberInfo @using)
        {
            if (@using is PropertyInfo)     ((PropertyInfo) @using).SetValue(to, value);
            else                            ((FieldInfo) @using).SetValue(to, value);
        }

    }

}
```

Simply instantiate a PresentationMapper with a proper business class implementation and call GetById on the presentationMapper.  Adjust class names and tweak to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Tyree, much obliged. Your solutions, I think, seems very complicated to me. I,m fairly new to generics. My only intention here is to create some kind of "baseframework" where I can decouple the presentationlayer from the rest and use webforms, mvc etc. with this "baseframework" as to my needs. I'll look into your answer and get back to you in a while. Thanks Again for your time...